# Знак препинания после "там"

Tags: пунктуация

До алгебры точно уж доберусь — а там как пойдёт.

Можно ли после "там" поставить какой-нибудь знак препинания? Предполагается, что "там" звучит долго, протягивается в речи, а за ним следует короткая пауза:

А таааам... как пойдёт!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Со знаками возможны варианты (кроме запятой между "там" и "как"):

*До алгебры точно уж доберусь, а там — как пойдёт.*

*До алгебры точно уж доберусь, а тааам... как пойдёт.* (Долгую гласную можно посадить на дефисы: та-а-ам.)

*До алгебры точно уж доберусь — а там... как пойдёт.*

(После отточия не потеряйте пробел.)

Comment: А можно ведь и ничего не ставить?

Comment: Владимир, если ничего не ставить, а можно вполне и ничего не ставить, то это будет противоречить подвопросу в "Пояснениях": ***Предполагается, что "там" звучит долго, протягивается в речи, а за ним следует короткая пауза.***

Comment: А как определить грамматическую основу в "там как пойдёт", если не будет стоять ничего?

Comment: Ой, шоб я так жил... Ну мысленно замените "там" на "дальше", на "потом", может, сложится грамматическая основа?